# Automorphism group of the Klein quartic over field of characteristic 2,3,7(Hartshorne exercise IV.5.7)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$, and $X$ be the plane quartic curve defined by
$$x^3y+y^3z+z^3x=0,$$
which is the so-called *Klein quartic*. Hartshorne claims in exercise IV.5.7(b) of his book <*Algebraic Geometry*> that

> Assume $p\ne3$, then the group $\mathrm{Aut}\, X$ is the simple group of order $168$, whose order is the maximum $84(g-1)$ allowed by (Ex. 2.5).

For the case $p\ne2,3,7$, I found a proof in e.g. [Perng.pdf](http://sections.maa.org/mddcva/MeetingFiles/Fall2014Meeting/TalkSlides/Perng.pdf). A sketch: we can find $3$ special automorphisms represented by matrices
$$S=\begin{pmatrix}
\zeta&0&0\\
0&\zeta^4&0\\
0&0&\zeta^2
\end{pmatrix},\ T=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
1&0&0
\end{pmatrix},\ 
U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-7}}\begin{pmatrix}
\zeta-\zeta^6&\zeta^2-\zeta^5&\zeta^4-\zeta^3\\
\zeta^2-\zeta^5&\zeta^4-\zeta^3&\zeta-\zeta^6\\
\zeta^4-\zeta^3&\zeta-\zeta^6&\zeta^2-\zeta^5
\end{pmatrix},$$
where $\zeta$ is a primitive $7$-th root of unity (in $k$), and the group $G$ generated by $S,T,U$ is a simple group of order $168$, achieving the Hurwitz's bound, so $G=\mathrm{Aut}\,X$.

However, this proof fails for $p=2,3,7$. For $p=2,3$, the Hurwitz's bound $84(g-1)$ can fail. For $p=7$, $X$ has a double point $[1,2,4]$ (and no other singularities), and there is no $7$-th root of unity.

I want to solve this exercise for $p=2,7$. Also, I am curious about the case $p=3$, in which the Hurwitz's bound can fail and $\mathrm{Aut}\,X$ is probably of order $>168$. Any hint or reference?

**Edit:** I have recently found a paper [On Certain Curves of Genus Three with Many Automorphisms](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43685319), which solved the case $p=2,3$. For $p=3$ the group $\mathrm{Aut}\,X$ is just $PSU(3,3^2)$, the simple group of order $6048$. However, the singular case $p=7$ is still unsolved.

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/452418/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I cannot find anything useful for my question in it, since it works only on $k=\mathbb{C}$. The main obstruction 
 is that, for field $k$ of characteristic $7$ there is no $7$-th root of unity, so I cannot find an automorphism of order $7$.

Comment: Sorry. I added the link also to have an reference to some material on-site.